# How to create a view listing vocabularies (not terms)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9

I'm attempting to create a view that filters and displays a list of vocabularies however I can't seem to find an option to allows me to do so.

In the View settings, I see options for taxonomy terms, but no options for the taxonomies themselves.

I initially attempted to do so by creating a taxonomy term view, only showing the vocabulary it's a part of and then filtering by only unique results but that seems like an over complicated way to do it.

Is there an option in views to just display vocabularies?

Comment: Not by default.

Comment: You could use something like https://www.drupal.org/project/config_views to get that functionality